# Use of Execute As User in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, execute

We are transitioning from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 and suddenly our Execute As User statements aren't working.  Did something change between these 2 releases?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have synced the login used for that user and the login has the same permissions as in SQL 2005